# How do I get the column from ColumnHeaderContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I have a `GridView` with its `GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu` set with two buttons. How would I get the column that opened the `ContextMenu`?

XAML (For ContextMenu):

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu MenuItem.Click="ContextMenu_Click" >
        <MenuItem Name="btnAsc" Header="Sort Ascending"/>
        <MenuItem Name="btnDesc" Header="Sort Descending"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void ContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    if (e.Source == btnAsc)
    {
        Sort(null, true);
    }
    else
    {
        Sort(null, false);
    }
}

//Sort a column based on if Ascending
private void Sort(GridViewColumnHeader column, bool isAsc)
{
    // Sorting Occurs here (This Works)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the GridViewColumnHeader by casting the sender argument to a ContextMenu and access its PlacementTarget property:

```
private void ContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
        GridViewColumnHeader header = contextMenu.PlacementTarget as GridViewColumnHeader;

        if (e.Source == btnAsc)
        {
            Sort(header, true);
        }
        else
        {
            Sort(header, false);
        }
    }
```